# How can I view tensor values that cause a TensorFlow crash?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get names of Tensors using a Tensor hashtable but I keep encountering a default value because the key was not found in the table. I have no idea why the key I am looking for is not found in the table. The problem is I have no idea how to actually see which key is giving the error.

```
table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(
      tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(tensor_ids, indexs), -1)
pids_toget = []
for i in range(FLAGS.batch_size):
  name = tf.gather(filenames, i)
  index_toget = table.lookup(name)

  pids_toget.append(index_toget)

tensor_vals = tf.Variable(np_clinical, dtype=tf.float32)



clinic_features_tensor = tf.gather(tensor_vals, pids_toget)
```

The error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py", line 50, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/ubuntu/scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py", line 46, in main
    inception_train.train(dataset, pids, np_clinical)
  File "/home/ubuntu/scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_train.py", line 373, in train
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: indices[348] = -1 is not in [0, 891)
         [[node GatherV2_400 (defined at /scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_train.py:253) ]]
         [[tower_7/mixed_35x35x288a/branch_pool/Conv/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSub/_6375]]
  (1) Invalid argument: indices[348] = -1 is not in [0, 891)
         [[node GatherV2_400 (defined at /scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_train.py:253) ]]

Input Source operations connected to node GatherV2_400:
 Variable/read (defined at /scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_train.py:251)

Input Source operations connected to node GatherV2_400:
 Variable/read (defined at /scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_train.py:251)

Original stack trace for 'GatherV2_400':
  File "/scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py", line 50, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py", line 46, in main
    inception_train.train(dataset, pids, np_clinical)
  File "/scipts/01_training/xClasses/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_train.py", line 253, in train
    clinic_features_tensor = tf.gather(tensor_vals, pids_toget)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 3475, in gather
    return gen_array_ops.gather_v2(params, indices, axis, name=name)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4097, in gather_v2
    batch_dims=batch_dims, name=name)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

I run the session here. I have tried using printnames = tf.Print(filenames) and print the filenames for that batch but it does not work for the batch that crashes.

```
# Build an initialization operation to run below.
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    tbinit = tf.initializers.tables_initializer()

    # Start running operations on the Graph. allow_soft_placement must be set to
    # True to build towers on GPU, as some of the ops do not have GPU
    # implementations.
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement))
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(tbinit)

    if FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path:
      try:
        assert tf.gfile.Exists(FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path)
        variables_to_restore = slim.variables.get_variables_to_retore_except_logits()
        restorer = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
        restorer.restore(sess, FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path)
        print('%s: Pre-trained model restored from %s' %
              (datetime.now(), FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path))
      except:
        #restorer = tf.train.import_meta_graph(FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path + '.meta')
        variables_to_restore = slim.variables.get_variables_to_retore_except_logits()
        restorer = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
        restorer.restore(sess, FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path)

    # Start the queue runners.
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(
        FLAGS.train_dir,
        graph=sess.graph)

    for step in range(FLAGS.max_steps):
      start_time = time.time()

      p2, _, loss_value = sess.run([printnames, train_op, loss,])
      print(p2)
      duration = time.time() - start_time
```

I have tried using try/except statements but I cannot get those to work to produce the names I need either. Is it even possible? It seems like sess.run just crashes.

Comment: Maybe some of the assertion operations under [`tf.debugging`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/debugging) can help?

Comment: It doesn't appear to help. I wish there was a way to just return the key that you tried to use in the hashtable when it is not found in it